# XSL transformation doc in java

Tags: java, xslt

I am a noob in XSLT area, trying to do a XML to XML transform and I have the following XML

```
<test>
  true
</test>
<test1>
  false
</test1>
```

**Desired transformed XML output:**

```
<object>
<boolean name="test">
  true
</boolean>
<boolean name="test1">
  false
</boolean>
</object>
```

I am very new to XSL transformation and I want to transform this XML using a XSLT doc. I am doing the xsl transform in java. I figured out how to transform the XML in java but struck at the XSLT document.

Any help or pointers on how to do the transformation will be greatly appreciated. So far I have understood this and this is what I have

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
    //select everything from root of the document  
    <xsl:template match="/">
```

**//for each element with value = true or false I want to add a parent node called object**

```
<xsl:for-each select=".">
    <object>
    </object>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: is your desired output a valid xml??

Comment: @Saurav sorry my bad, copy paste error, updated my que. Thanks for catching that for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for each element with value = true or false I want to add a parent
>   node called object

First, you must have a well-formed input, with a single root element, say:

**XML**

```
<root>
<test>
  true
</test>
<test1>
  false
</test1>
</root>
```

Then you can do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <object>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[normalize-space(.)='true' or normalize-space(.)='false']">
            <boolean name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </boolean>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </object>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<object>
   <boolean name="test">
  true
</boolean>
   <boolean name="test1">
  false
</boolean>
</object>
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I am actually transforming a json to XML using org.json.XML.toString in java, how do I create a root parent for the output json ? sorry if this is too basic ( I can alter the Json obj but want to do it the right way)

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about that.

Comment: I got that part figured out how do I check for string,integer, boolean basically any data type for each element within a XSLT document. I can ask it as a separate question, sorry to bother.

Comment: I suggest you do, because it may not be as simple as it might seem. Make sure to state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, whether your document has a schema and whether your processor is schema-aware.

Comment: please look into this followup question and help me out if you get a chance, thanks a ton for the help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059437/identifying-data-type-for-every-element-inside-a-xsl