# Identifying data type for every element inside a XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

As a follow up to this answer, is there a way I can figure out if the data type of the XML values?
[XSL transformation doc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056695/xsl-transformation-doc-in-java/32056937)

eg:

```
<root>
<test>
  true
</test>
<test1>
  1
</test1>
<test2>
  "abc"
</test2>
</root>
```

My thought:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <object>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[normalize-space(.)]">
                <xsl:choose>        
                    <xsl:when test="contains(., 3)">//  want to check for Integer
                        <Integer name="{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </Integer>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        //check for string, boolean
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </object>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to know how I would be able to identify in XSL the data type of 1,"abc",true as integer,string and boolean? If someone can help me understand how normalize-space(.) works it would be very helpful (:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of XSLT? (If >= 2.0, you can use `castable as`.) Also, `1` and `0` are both castable as both integer and boolean; which should they be?

Comment: Also, re: `normalize-space()` check out the summary in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space

Comment: @DanielHaley The example provided has 1.0, if it is just a switch of 1.0 to 2.0 that would let me use castable I am open for 2.0. About 1 and 0 they need to be considered as integers and not booleans

Comment: In addition to changing the version number in your XSLT, you'd also have to use a 2.0 processor (like Saxon).

Comment: @DanielHaley I can handle 2.0 no problem, I am running this XSLT in eclipse and using transformer in java to write out a transformed XML output. I tested the XSLT with 2.0 and my output is still fine with the updated version

Comment: I added a 2.0 answer, but just changing the version to 2.0 and checking to see if you still have output is not a good enough check. You'll know for sure though if you see errors like `Extra illegal tokens: 'castable', 'as'...` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`castable as`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-castable) in XSLT 2.0 to check if the value of the element is castable as either `xs:integer` or `xs:boolean` (or any of the other xs [datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#built-in-datatypes)).

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <test>
        true
    </test>
    <test1>
        1
    </test1>
    <test2>
        "abc"
    </test2>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test|test1|test2">
        <xsl:variable name="type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="normalize-space() castable as xs:integer">
                    <xsl:text>Integer</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="normalize-space() castable as xs:boolean">
                    <xsl:text>Boolean</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>String</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$type}">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <Boolean name="test">true</Boolean>
   <Integer name="test1">1</Integer>
   <String name="test2">"abc"</String>
</root>
```

If your XML is using a schema and your processor is schema aware, you could also use [`instance of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-instance-of) to check the type.

Also, you could use an `if` statement instead of the `xsl:choose` if you find it easier to read...

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="
    if (normalize-space() castable as xs:integer) then 
        'Integer' 
    else if (normalize-space() castable as xs:boolean) then 
        'Boolean' 
    else 
        'String'
"/>
```